# Counting total characters of a file

Tags: c#

Hi I'm pretty new to C# and trying to do some exercises to get up to speed with it. I'm trying to count the total number of characters in a file but it's stopping after the first word, would someone be able to tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance

```
 public void TotalCharacterCount()
        {
            string str;
            int count, i, l;
            count  = i = 0;

            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\Lewis\\file.txt");
            str = reader.ReadLine();
            l = str.Length;


                while (str != null && i < l)
                {

                    count++;

                    i++;

                    str = reader.ReadLine();
                }



            reader.Close();
            Console.Write("Number of characters in the file is : {0}\n", count);


        }
```

Comment: well, why do you check i > 0?

Comment: it is also more readable when you have the variables on separate line

Comment: not int count, i, l;
            count  = i = 0;
but 
int I = 0;
int l = 0;
int count = i;

Comment: maybe that's why you break after the first word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the size of a file:

```
long length = new System.IO.FileInfo("C:\\Users\\Lewis\\file.txt").Length;
Console.Write($"Number of characters in the file is : {length}");
```

If you want to count characters to play around with C#, then here is some sample code that might help you

```
            int totalCharacters = 0;

            // Using will do the reader.Close for you. 
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\Lewis\\file.txt"))
            {
                string str = reader.ReadLine();

                while (str != null)
                {
                    totalCharacters += str.Length;
                    str = reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            // If you add the $ in front of the string, then you can interpolate expressions 
            Console.Write($"Number of characters in the file is : {totalCharacters}");
```

Comment: not sure what's going on but I'm trying to up vote your answer but it's coming up with -1 for some reason

Comment: Thank you very much Lewis! and go ahead with C#, it is a great language that can build very big things :)

Answer (score 0):

> it's stopping after the first word

It is because you have check `&& i < l` in the loop and then increment it so the check doesn't pass you don't change the value of l variable(by the way, the name is not very good, I was sure it was `1`, not `l`).

Then if you need to get total count of characters in the file you could read the whole file to a string variable and just get it from Count() Length

```
var count = File.ReadAllText(path).Count();
```

Getting Length property of the FileInfo will give [the size, in bytes, of the current file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length?view=netframework-4.8), which is not necessary will be equal to characters count(depending on Encoding a character may take more than a byte)

And regarding the way you read - it also depends whether you want to count new line symbols and others or not.

Consider the following sample

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sampleWithEndLine = "a\r\n";
    var length1 = "a".Length;
    var length2 = sampleWithEndLine.Length;
    var length3 = @"a
".Length;

    Console.WriteLine($"First sample: {length1}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Second sample: {length2}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Third sample: {length3}");
    var totalCharacters = 0;
    File.WriteAllText("sample.txt", sampleWithEndLine);

    using(var reader = File.OpenText("sample.txt"))
    {
        string str = reader.ReadLine();

        while (str != null)
        {
            totalCharacters += str.Length;
            str = reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Second sample read with stream reader: {totalCharacters}");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

For the second sample, first, the Length will return 3, because it actually contains three symbols, while with stream reader you will get 1, because [The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed. The returned value is null if the end of the input stream is reached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Comment: Viktor, this has landed in the Low Quality Answer review queue because it lacks explanation as to why it could be an answer. I know you wrote a number of comments and you may think those suffice. Comments, however, tend to get deleted over time and not everyone using the site may associate those with this contribution. Please use the [edit] link below this answer to add explanatory information as to why this solves the question, perhaps with a remark as to how it differs from what has been marked as "the" answer, already.